# Python convert nested array to cython c array

Tags: python, algorithm, nested, cython

I want to convert array of array which have default value of zeros in each array. The reason to do this is that I want to convert a high computing algorithm from python to cython to speed up computation more. The code for array is like this for python:

```
self.v = [[0 for i in range(self.D)] for j in range(self.NP)]  #velocity
self.Sol = [[0 for i in range(self.D)] for j in range(self.NP)]
```

`self.D` and `self.NP` could be any integer values. The format of the sample data in python is like this, for `self.D=4` and `self.NP=3`:

[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: This a python list- or list of lists.  More often when python users talk of arrays, they using `numpy`.  `np.zeros((3,4), dtype=int)` makes an analogous `numpy` array.

Comment: Thanks but I want to convert it to cython. You mean that it has much more speed than compiled cython?

Comment: I don't think a "cython c array" actually exists as a concept (or if it does then it's ambiguous and could mean multiple things)

Comment: To clarify - do you want an array with a fixed size known at compile time, one that's dynamically allocated with C malloc/free, quick access to a numpy-like array, or something else entirely?

Comment: @DavidW Well because I know the parameter values, it cab be static and defined in code. For example for simple array I defined a float one like this and worked: `cdef array.array Fitness` `self.best = array.array('f') #[0] * self.D ` . But for above I don't know how to define it.